# Disable Redis AutoConfig in spring boot when testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to disable Redis when I am testing with spring boot. I have disabled my configuration but the auto config created a default connection and fails because it can't connect to a non-existent service. For testing I am content to just use a basic in-memory cache or a no-op cache. That doesn't work either. Here is what I have tried:

per [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5386) I added said configuration to my test app properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
```

But. That gets me a bit further. But ultimately I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` `redisTemplate` - this is because `redisReferenceResolver` is trying to look that up.

Looking at my debugger right now, the bean it's trying to hydrate is:
`org.springframework.data.redis.core.convert.ReferenceResolverImpl` which is coming from `spring-data-redis:1.8.0.RELEASE` which is coming from this dependency: `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')` . I admit, the bean name is a bit misleading. The type it actually resolves to is not

The only other reference to redis is in our hibernate support.

Can someone explain how to turn this off for testing?

Answer (score 20):

- Try excluding this two auto-configuration classes in your test properties file:
  `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`

or

- exclude
  `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration`
  and set: `spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled=false`

Comment: When I return to the code that was causing me this issue I will give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

With YAML syntax (& Spring Boot):

```
spring.autoconfigure:
  exclude:
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
    - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```

If you have [SystemEnvironmentPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SystemEnvironmentPropertySource.html) in you app context you can use environment variable `SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE` separating items with comma:

```
SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```

Also try `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {...})` on a `@TestConfiguration` annotated class.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to change any files/code, you can also do this with an environment variable:

```
SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```